# HTML code getter using SWT Browser

Tags: java, html, eclipse, swt

How I can get html-page code to String using SWT Broser?

```
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setSize(100, 100);


    Browser browser = new Browser(shell, SWT.NONE);
    browser.setBounds(5, 75, 100, 100);

    shell.open();
    browser.setUrl("https://google.com");

    String html = browser.getText(); //NOTHING!

    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {

        if (!display.readAndDispatch() && html == null) {

            display.sleep();
        }
    }

    display.dispose();

    Syste.out.println(html); ////NOTHING!
```

So, how I can take html? And best way, when after html-code getting the display window will close?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you are searching for is: [`Browser#getText()`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/browser/Browser.html#getText%28%29). Here is the important part of the javadoc:

> Returns a string with HTML that represents the content of the current page.

So this would do the job:

```
String html = browser.getText();

System.out.println(html);
```

---

For your second question: You can close the shell by calling [`Shell#close()`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Shell.html#close%28%29). Here is the Javadoc:

> Requests that the window manager close the receiver in the same way it would be closed when the user clicks on the "close box" or performs some other platform specific key or mouse combination that indicates the window should be removed.

Comment: I think you meant `browser.getText()` in your example.

Comment: @Baz, Sorry, my mistake... 

Sure, Browser#getText() doesn'twork!

Comment: @iKrumping This may be due to the fact, that the page didn't load yet. Try waiting for some seconds between calling `setUrl()` and `getText()`.

Comment: @Baz, yeah! thanks, man. The problem solved by adding `ProgressListener` into `Browser`.